# How to merge rows with in a group

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I need to merge rows by comparing with different columns.

Here is an example which is a result of a complex join

Input

```
keycolumn       val1     val2
  a             abc      
  a             xyz      
  a                       abc
  a                       xyz
  a             pqr
```

Desired Result

```
keycolumn        val1     val2
  a               abc      abc
  a               xyz      xyz
  a               pqr
```

I'm tying to see if the desired result can be obtained without using join

Comment: How can we tell wich records should be grouped together?

Comment: keycolumn should be used to group, if val1 value in one record is in val2 column of another record or vice versa, then they should be shown as single record instead of 2 records

Comment: OK. And what should we do if no corresponding record exists?

Comment: If not record exists then the corresponding value would be null, but one of those two columns will always have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-`LEFT JOIN` the table on matching `keycolumn` and `val1/val2` tuples and use `DISTINCT` and `COALESCE()` to print out the relevant values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.keycolumn,
    COALESCE(t1.val1, t2.val1) val1, 
    COALESCE(t1.val2, t2.val2) val2
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 
    ON t1.keycolumn = t2.keycolumn 
    AND (t1.val1 = t2.val2 OR t1.val2 = t2.val1)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qCjaUVxge4uTq6CPeCac/1)**:

```
| keycolumn | val1 | val2 |
| --------- | ---- | ---- |
| a         | abc  | abc  |
| a         | xyz  | xyz  |
| a         | pqr  |      |
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select keycolumn, max(val1) as val1, max(val2) as val2
from ((select t.keycolumn, t.val1, null as val2, row_number() over () as seqnum
       from t
       where val1 is not null
      ) union all
      (select t.keycolumn, null as val1, t.val2, row_number() over () as seqnum
       from t
       where val2 is not null
      )
     ) t
group by keycolumn, seqnum
order by keycolumn, seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8dc9535076a5b06759579e6fa1338f66) is a db<>fiddle.  Depending on the database, you might need an `order by` for the `row_number()` (the db fiddle uses Postgres which doesn't require `order by`).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
select t1.keycolumn, t1.val1,
    (select t2.val2 from table1 t2 where t2.keycolumn = t1.keycolumn and t2.val2 = t1.val1)
from table1 t1
where t1.val1 is not null
```